# How Do I Prevent "Argument not optional" error when using Javascript clearTimeout() with IE9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, settimeout

The following Javascript code works in all browsers except IE9. What's the fix?

```
setTimeout('doSomething();clearTimeout();',500);
```

The debugger says that it's expecting me to pass an ID number to clearTimeout(), when all I'm doing is clearing all timeouts.

Comment: Why did Microsoft have to break this? Worked just fine before!

Comment: It's bad practice to pass a string to setTimeout. Pass a function instead.

Comment: Well, there's really not much point in trying to clear a timeout that's already timed out.

Comment: Why do you need clearTimeout there at all? Once it is already running there is no sense for clearTimeout

Comment: @JonathanLonowski `...I'm doing is clearing **all** timeouts..`

Comment: I'd push all timeouts to an array then clear them in a `for` loop in that case.

Comment: `clearTimeout()` with no argument does _not_ clear all timeouts. It just does nothing in all browsers; MDN documents it as ["Passing an invalid ID to clearTimeout does not have any effect (and doesn't throw an exception"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout), and running without argument is the same as running with `undefined` argument, which _is_ an invalid timeout ID. Test case: `setTimeout(function() { console.log('timeout') }, 1000); clearTimeout();` Chrome still logs the 'timeout' message.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté That's exactly how I would manage it as well. If you were just blindly clearing everything how do you know your not stepping on some other scripts toes?

Comment: @asawyer Exactly, nice observation. `=]` Same goes for when I remove listeners with jQuery, always passing a named function reference to [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to prevent it from removing unrelated listeners (slightly off-topic but I see OP answers in jQuery as well).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have said, `clearTimeout()` without any arguments doesn't do anything. `clearTimeout()` requires you to specify which timeout you want to clear. This applies in all browsers. Maybe only IE is reporting the error, but it's causing a problem in all of them.

Perhaps the reason you're calling `clearTimeout()` is that you think the `setTimeout()` needs to be cleared in case it keeps getting called? This is incorrect -- `setTimeout()` causes its code to be called just once, after the given amount of time.

Therefore, since you're trying to clear the timeout after it's already been triggered, there's nothing to clear anyway.

There is a separate command called `setInterval()` which does trigger a repeating timeout. This would need to be cleared to stop it calling over and over and over, but it's generally considered to be a bad idea to use `setInterval()` anyway, so I won't dwell on it too much here.

The other thing you should do is avoid calling `setInterval` with a string parameter. Just specify the function you want to call directly, instead.

In short, your code should look like this:

```
setTimeout(doSomething,500);
```

That should be sufficient for your example to work fine in all browsers.

As I said, you don't need to clear the timeout in your case, but in case you do need to clear it in another instance, you would need to have `setTimeout` (or `setInterval`) return a value. This value is a reference object to the timer, and this reference is what you need to pass into `clearTimeout`.

ie:

```
var timer;
....
timer = setTimeout(doSomething,500);
....
....
//something happened, I need to cancel the timeout:
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Hope that helps clear things up.

Comment: It does clear this up. I had become used to using it, borrowing from a previous programmer who must have screwed this up. I won't do this anymore.